# cordva,ionic project in Visual Studio 2015 Build errors

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

**I Have Copied this project from visual studio 2013 to visual studio 2015**

I am developing mobile app using apache cordova in visual studio. Its gets build successfully when I select other than android - device .

when I select android - device it gives me following errors  and I am using apache codova update 10

Please help me how to build program successfully

```
Error FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Error Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.

Error > D:\MOBILE PROJECTS\FINAL_PROJECTS\WhollyCow.Customer.App\WhollyCow.Customer.App\platforms\
       android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png:
       Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : D:\MOBILE PROJECTS\FINAL_PROJECTS\WhollyCow.Customer.App\WhollyCow.Customer.App\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\
      appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_activated_mtrl_alpha.9.png    

Error       * Try:
Error   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log 
Error Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,""D:\MOBILE 
      PROJECTS\FINAL_PROJECTS\WhollyCow.Customer.App\WhollyCow.Customer.App\platforms\android\gradlew" cdvBuildDebug -b 
     "D:\MOBILE PROJECTS\FINAL_PROJECTS\WhollyCow.Customer.App\WhollyCow.Customer.App\platforms\android\build.gradle" -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are hitting the MAX PATH limit on Windows.

Can you try to build a blank project for the same platform in a shorter path?

Comment: @rido is right move your project to C:\ and it will work.